# Creating an external table on cnosdb in the format of `ndjson` is invalid

Tags: sql, cnosdb

Creating an external table in the format of 'ndjson' is invalid,
no data found

#### To Reproduce

1. Create a `ndjson` format data file

```bash
echo -e '{"name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York"}\n{"name": "Alice", "age": 25, "city": "Los Angeles"}\n{"name": "Bob", "age": 35, "city": "Chicago"}' > basic.ndjson
```

2. Create an external table using the 'cnosdb cli' command line

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE basic (
     name  STRING NOT NULL,
     age     INT NOT NULL,
     city    STRING NOT NULL,
)
STORED AS NDJSON
WITH HEADER ROW
LOCATION '/basic.ndjson';
```

3. query

```sql
select * from basic
```

No data returned

#### Expected behavior

```sql
+-------+-----+-------------+
| name  | age | city        |
+-------+-------------------+
| John  | 30  | New York    |
| Alice | 25  | Los Angeles |
| Bob   | 35  | Chicago     |
```

#### Additional context

Version: cnosdb 2.3.4, revision 6765f19dcc86f9df02c225c139912d50769457ac